# jQuery .append() textarea to div has .val() undefined

Tags: jquery, textarea, undefined

What's wrong with this?

```
<button id='myButton'>Click me</button>

<p>Borken</p>
<div id='RS_msgBox'></div>

<hr />


<!-- This is the control. The structure is exactly the same as when after 
     the JS gets done .appending to #RS_msgBox -->

<p>Works</p>
<div id='RS_msgBox2'>
    <div id='RS_msgs2'>
        <textarea id='RS_text2' cols=50 rows=5>
            I was here before any JS affected me.
        </textarea>
    </div>
</div>


jQuery('#myButton').click(function () {

    var msgDiv  = jQuery("#RS_text"),
        msgDiv2 = jQuery("#RS_text2"),
        logOne  = '\nI am the first log entry. ',
        logTwo  = "\nHey, where is the first entry? ";

    jQuery("#RS_msgBox").append("<div id='RS_msgs'><textarea id='RS_text' cols=50 rows=5>I was via JS append().</textarea></div>");

    // Experiment
    console.log('Before:'+msgDiv.val());
    msgDiv.val(msgDiv.val()+logOne); // Doesn't work because msgDiv.val() is undefined at this point.  But why?? I 'defined' it when I .append()ed it, didn't I?
    console.log('After:'+msgDiv.val());

    // Control
    msgDiv2.val(msgDiv2.val()+logOne);

    // Appending further text still fails whether we call another function or not.
    anotherFunc(logTwo);
});

function anotherFunc(newText) {
    var msgDiv = jQuery("textarea#RS_text"),
        msgDiv2 = jQuery("textarea#RS_text2");

    msgDiv.val(msgDiv.val()+newText);
    msgDiv2.val(msgDiv2.val()+newText);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/t3knocrat/NZLjd/

tl;dr: Why can't I `.append()` a `<textarea>` to a `<div>` and set a `.val(logOne)` to it immediately? More importantly, how to fix/work around?

--

I've found answers on SO that *almost* answer my question, but none really explain WHY the recently created `<textarea>` doesn't get appended, or HOW to work around it.

In other words, I'm certain that this is a duplicate question by now, but I haven't found the one that answers my two questions (why? & how?).

I'm *guessing* that the browser needs a little time to `.append()` the `<textarea>` to the DOM, and the code works asynchronously. In other words, the code just "*skips*" setting the `.val(logOne)` because `#RS_text` isn't ready yet (no errors thrown, caught or handled), and it just continues on it's merry way to setting `.val(logTwo)` to `#RS_text2`.

Does anyone know if that sounds anywhere near correct?

Ultimately, I suppose what's more important is how to fix/work around this.  The goal is to have a text area created for the sole purpose of receiving notes/log entries from the remainder of the javascript (via node and socket.io).  And this code *DOES* work on the second time around, when the `<textarea>` has been created and a new log entry is sent to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first problem is you build

```
msgDiv  = jQuery("#RS_text"),
```

before you append, at a time where it doesn't exist yet so the collection is empty. Put that initialization after the appending of the textarea.

Another problem is that your create more than one element with the same ID.

Comment: I got the same conclusion :)

Comment: It's easy to find bugs in the provided code but I'm unsure of what's the goal. I made this : http://jsfiddle.net/RJFYK/

Comment: That's the problem, jQuery tries to find the provided id but it cannot find it. Editing the original jsFiddle with this answer fixes the problem http://jsfiddle.net/NZLjd/2/

Comment: Ahh, Thanks dystroy! I'm sure that'll do it.  The multiple ID problem appears only in my example code.